# Git のユーザー名設定時にエラーが表示される

Tags: git

#### 解決したいこと

[image: スクリーンショット 2021-10-10 15.35.15.png]

上のスクショのStep:Gitにユーザー名を追加するの項目を学習していて、ターミナルで$ git config --global user.username と入力しているのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

[image: スクリーンショット 2021-10-10 15.35.32.png]

スクショの下から２行目にある通り、zsh: parse error near `\n'という表示が出てしまい、Gitにユーザー名を追加することができません。

#### 自分で試したこと

このエラーがなんなのかGoogleで検索などをかけてみたのですが、はっきりとした解答が得られずこうして質問をさせていただきました。どなたかご存知のかた対処法をお教え願います。

Comment: git以前にコマンド入力方法とエスケープ規則を学ぶ必要がありそうです。

Comment: スクリーンショット内に「例の中の"<"と">"は入力する必要はありませんので注意して下さい」と書かれていますよ。

Comment: 先ほど< >を外して実行したら、すんなりと実行することができました。まだまだプログラミング初学者なので、こういった常識が分からないところがありますが、ともかく回答いただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

コメントでも指摘がありますが、`<>` の記号はシェルにとって特別な意味を持つのでコマンド入力の画面では扱いに注意が必要です。

手っ取り早くは `<>` をユーザー名に含めずコマンドを実行して下さい。

```
$ git config --global user.username USERNAME
```